# How exactly does one install `.egg` files?

Tags: macos, installation, python

When I tried downloading [the Sphinx installer here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Sphinx/), my computer couldn’t find a default application to run the installer.

`easy_install` doesn’t work either.  I’m running Python 2.7 but only have `easy_install` for 2.5 and 2.6

Furthermore, the [analogous one for 2.7 is an `.egg` file](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/).

Comment: I'm running Mac OS 10.6.8.

Comment: I think easy_install has been replaced by pip, try `pip install sphinx`. Also, the egg file is just a zip, so you could unzip it and then use `python setup.py install`.

Comment: unzip setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg didn't work after I downloaded the .egg, and I still can't open it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh, Sphinx' egg is a zip file, but setuptools seems like a bash file, [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/#cygwin-mac-os-x-linux-other) says to run as `sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg --prefix=~`

Comment: I did that as well - it says that there's no such file or directory (I couldn't unzip sphinx either).

Answer (score 3):

The *.egg* file may be generated as part of the installation, rather than used to perform the installation.  In that instance, the installation package is a directory with the following (or similar) [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286690/how-do-i-create-and-load-an-egg-file-in-python).

```
my_project/
    my_module/
        __init__.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
setup.py
```

With the *Anaconda Distribution* of python, the installation can then be performed within *Anaconda Prompt*.  If a virtual environment is used, it should first be activated.

```
conda activate C:\[path]\virtual_environment_name
```

The *setup.py* file included in the command to perform the installation  may require a specific version of the *setuptools* python library.  Even earlier versions of python tend to be bundled with the latest *setuptools* library, which may not be compatible with the required *setup.py* file. If compatibility issues are encountered, the following *setuptools* version installation within *Anaconda Prompt* may resolve them (with the virtual environment activated, if applicable).

```
pip install setuptools==58.2.0
```

One must then navigate to the package directory within *Anaconda Prompt* (with the virtual environment activated, if applicable).

```
cd C:\[path]\my_project
```

Then, the following command is used.

```
python setup.py install
```

Once the installation is complete, an *.egg* file may be present inside the python packages directory (the file will have been generated as part of the installation).  [A python interpreter can then load python modules directly from the *.egg* file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604600/why-does-easy-install-extract-some-python-eggs-and-not-other)

Comment: Did this come from chatgpt?

Comment: No, I am currently working with an .egg file and I found that a synthesis of information on (at least my instance of) installation and usage was lacking. I am hoping my answer might be helpful to others.

Comment: The tone sounded like chatgpt.  Gave it a boost now.

Comment: Thank you for the boost.

Answer (score 2):

`python -m easy_install <package>.egg`

Answer (score 1):

You can go to this [setuptools page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8) and download the `ez_setup.py` script. Open the terminal emulator and type

```
sudo python /path/to/your/ez_setup.py
```

Later you will install the setuptools and the `easy_install` command will be available for your python. Then you just need to type `easy_install` to install you egg file.